# What are the limitations of the devnet?

Tags: spl-token, devnet

I am running an SPL token program that is used as a currency. Only my wallet can issue this token. I am on the devnet and while I understand that Solana tokens are not real, I do not understand what the risk to my project is. What disadvantage is there for me to leave my project on the devnet forever.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of downsides. For one, Devnet is unstable. The infrastructure that runs Devnet is significantly worse than on Mainnet. There are also significantly less nodes, which means theres a higher likelihood of the account state or history being lost. Also, full ledger history isn't easily accessible. Since nodes on Solana don't require transaction history to gain consensus, full ledger history is rare on Devnet, and most RPC providers don't even have that data. Because there's so few nodes, Devnet is also super centralized. I think Solana Labs/Foundation has a supermajority of the Devnet stake at the moment as well, which is not good for decentralization. (the explorer isn't working and I'm not at my pc so I can't verify this, but they either have a supermajority or a very large stake).

Devnet is for testing new programs. If you want the guarantees that blockchains give you (decentralization, stability, permanent history, etc.), don't use Devnet. Use Mainnet Beta.

Comment: Plus you'll have to beg others for SOL on devnet because requesting via airdrop rarely works.